# What resolution does my in-app artwork need to be?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

What resolution does in-app artwork need to be to make use of the high-resolution iPhone 4 display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly double the normal resolution images.  If you had someImage.png that was 44x320 before, then create someImage@2x.png that is 88x640 for high resolution.

Comment: A little clarification: Make sure you provide the low-res file as well as the hi-res file. All you need to do is add the @2x-suffix to the filename, so iPhone 4 will find it automatically. If no hi-res image is found, the low-res image will be used, just like on an iPhone 3G.

Comment: Another addition.. so far it only works with certain image handlers like `UIImage imageNamed` ..I think Apple is working on the others

Comment: how do I name my file? myFile@2x.png?

Comment: Yes, `[UIImage imageNamed:]` looks for files with `@2x` just before the extension.

Comment: If I design my apps in IB, can I just select the @2X image and assume the iPhone OS will select the right one for lower models?

Comment: Yes.  IB files use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I also got confused with all the artwork options. therefore i created an overview of all the artwork options for iOS devices with some explanation and a workflow tip. See my overview at: http://www.mobiledev.nl/ios-artwork-what-icons-and-images-are-needed-for-an-ios-app/